inappbrowser-reborn react native auth failed in android build release
I have an auth flow using react-native-inappbrowser-reborn. I have the redirect deeplink set up and working for both Android and iOS debug build. However on android when I build release, after login success the browser instantly dismiss and response:
{"message": "chrome tabs activity destroyed", "type": "dismiss"}

the redirect deeplink is demo://success?token='abc'
it work fine both iOS and android debug build and also iOS release build except android
AndroidManifest.xml
 <intent-filter android:label="demo app">
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
       <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
       <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
       <data android:scheme="demo" android:host="success"/> 
</intent-filter>

My login
onPress={async () => {
  try {
     //when login success web will redirect to this demo://sucess?token='abc'
     //Config.baseUrlTwo = "https://demo.com/"
     const browser = await InAppBrowser.openAuth(Config.baseUrlTwo + "oauth/authenticate",
              "demo://success",
              { forceCloseOnRedirection: false, showInRecents: true }
            );
            if (browser && browser.type === "success") {
              let token = "";
              let getToken = browser.url.match(/'([^']+)'/g) || [];
              if (getToken.length) {
                getToken = getToken.map((match) => match.slice(1, -1));
                token = getToken[0];
              } else if (browser.url.includes("%27")) {
                getToken = browser.url.split("%27") || [];
                if (getToken.length) {
                  token = getToken[1];
                }
              }
              if (token !== "") {
                props.dispatch(Login({ token, ...props }));
              }
            } else {
              Alert.alert(JSON.stringify(browser));
            }
          } catch (error) {
            Alert.alert(error.message);
          }
        }}

I have no idea where this bug come from

I have a similar issue. Getting response {     "message": "chrome tabs activity destroyed",     "type": "dismiss" } on Android for expected success case. On iOS it works just fine.
Even on android the auth is successful because if I log the URL, I get my expected token in there, but it's strange that the response is response {     "message": "chrome tabs activity destroyed",     "type": "dismiss" } @CyberCrime did you solve this?

@CezarCobuz Yes I found the issue.

@CezarCobuzIn my situation, my app uses a universal link, so when inapp-browser reroutes to matcch that exact URL (for example, "foo.com"), Android assumes I've opened the app, which is why inapp-browser closes right away.

Please make sure:

You wrap your code inside an if check: await InAppBrowser.isAvailable()
The demo://success is working in Release App. Try enter that url in a note app and press the link if it can start the App
Try switching forceCloseOnRedirection to true or false.

Bonus: As per their document, please also try adding RNInAppBrowserModule.onStart(this);, it will helps checking if the browser is supported/available and starting it as soon as the App start.

thaks a lot, I tried but It still doesn't work.
